# LoadRunner: how to create a DLL to use "web_reg_save_param" function with

Tags: c, dll, loadrunner

Trying to test an ASP system which returns some very large `viewstate` parameters, causing vugen to crash on playback.

I have read it's possible to create a DLL to do the correlation with, e.g. - I have created a function that uses `web_reg_save_param` and wish to put this in my DLL and then include it in my LR script and call the function.  I'm hoping this would resolve the memory crash issue with vugen.

Does anyone have any experience of this?

I'm encountering the following problem when trying to build the DLL:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FunviewDll, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  dllmain.cpp
1>  FunviewDll.cpp
1>FunviewDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__web_reg_save_param referenced in function "void __cdecl Funviewcs::Funview(void)" (?Funview@Funviewcs@@YAXXZ)
1>FunviewDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__web_reg_save_param_ex referenced in function "void __cdecl Funviewcs::Funview(void)" (?Funview@Funviewcs@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\z185876\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DynamicLibrary\Debug\FunviewDll.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm guessing it's trying to reference the source code for the "web_reg_save_param" function but I have no idea where to find this?

Anyone know where this could be found?  A DLL part of the LR install perhaps?

Really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  But you have found your first performance defect, the incredibly large viewstates.  Your developers likely have tossed everything into state, without deciding what is critical and what is not.  This will make you network bound and will also cause problems on older browsers which do not allow for such large variables.

So, start there. Report a defect related to a high dependency on network due to the size of the state management variables.  Then have someone go through and trim them.

Note:  I have used LoadRunner with vairables as large as 16 Megabytes, which was cited as a defect and trimmed down to a couple of 100K by the way. I have seen it work with variables ass large as 20 Megabytes.  This would mean that your solution set is in excess of 20 Megabytes.   Solve the large viewstates.